# MySQL week number with specific first day of the week

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, week-number

With the MySQL WEEK function I can set the first day of the week to Sunday or Monday. But how about if I need to set it to some other day?

The reason for this is that we have clients going through online programs that have a specific "check-in day" each week. For some it will be Monday, for some Tuesday, for some Wednesday and so on, and we need to see the averages of multiple check-ins for each week.

If it was always Sunday and Monday I can do something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(timestamp) AS year, WEEK(timestamp,1) AS week ... GROUP BY year, week
```

But there's thousands of clients and I need to get the weekly averages for each client, but each client will have their own first day of the week — going Monday to Sunday, Wednesday to Tuesday, Saturday to Friday and so on.

Any ideas how we can do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in. So you need to calculate the date of the first of each weekday in the year, then calculate the difference in weeks and use that.

Comment: Is that first day stored in the same table? It is a timestamp? Is it the first occurrence for that client in the table?

Comment: Thanks @Scratte it's not in the same table but we could add it in via a join and get access to it in the same query. Or we could have it in a variable before running the query that could just be inserted anywhere into the query. It's stored in the other table as a DATETIME called "entry_due_at", for example "2021-08-16 12:00:00".

Comment: OK.. So I take it the client is part of the where clause? You're not extracting this data for all clients at the same time?

Comment: @Scratte yes, exactly. We're always just showing the data for one client at a time, so each time the query is run the entry_due_at will be the same for all records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm calling your timestamp `time`, to not confuse it with a datatype:

```sql
CREATE TABLE clientdates(client VARCHAR(20),
                         time   TIMESTAMP)
```

I suggest you just subtract the `DAYOFWEEK("check-in day")`, which you in comments refer to as `entry_due_at` from the time. Then you'll get the offset you need for the `WEEK()` to work:

```sql
SET @client := 'client2';

-- in my example I just picked the first date the client had an entry
SELECT @weekday := DAYOFWEEK(min(time)) - 1 -- need 0 to 6
  FROM clientdates
 WHERE client = @client;

SELECT client,
       @weekday,
       YEAR(time) AS year,
       WEEK(time - INTERVAL @weekday DAY) AS week_offset,
       count(*)
  FROM clientdates
 WHERE client = @client
 GROUP BY client, year, week_offset
```

Running it with this data, which will have it's first day on a Thursday:

```sql
INSERT INTO clientdates
  VALUES ('client2', '2021-08-19 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-20 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-21 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-22 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-23 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-24 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-25 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-26 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-27 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-28 04:14:07.9'),
         ('client2', '2021-08-29 04:14:07.9');
```

I get this result:

| client | @weekday | year | week_offset | count(*) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client2 | 2 | 2021 | 33 | 7 |
| client2 | 2 | 2021 | 34 | 4 |

If you need to use `WEEK(time, 1)` instead, you'll just need to subtract 2 instead of 1 when getting the value for `@weekday`, since you need Monday to have the zero-indexed value instead of Sunday.

---

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6823ffa4d8972293238c048a2e170b87)

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly as needed, thanks so much for your help Scratte!

Comment: @Matt You're welcome :) Note that people flag comments with "thanks" in them. So these comments may go at any time.

Comment: Nice solution ;) Still here hahaha

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 That is nice to hear :) I hope you stay :)